# Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Указываются его фамилия, имя, отчество, место жительства(,) и если истец использует услуги адвоката, то и его данные как представителя".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всегда бывает сложно расставлять знаки препинания (атрибут исключительно письменной речи)в предложениях разговорного характера или с элементами разговорной речи. В данной, на первый взгляд совершенно официальной, книжной фразе есть пропуск сказуемого (чтобы избежать повтора). "*Указываются его фамилия, имя, отчество, место жительства, и если истец использует услуги адвоката, то (указываются)и его данные как представителя".* Предложение сложное. союзное. с сочинительной и подчинительной связью. И тогда знаки расставлены верно. Перед *И* - потому что соединяет предикативные части, перед *то* - запятая закрывает придаточное.  Перед *если* запятая не нужна, так как это часть составного союза если..то. (По-другому: в сложном предложении при стечении союзов запятая НЕ ставится, если есть продолжение союза - ТО, НО. Если нет - запятая ставится). Можно, конечно,рассудить и по-другому. НЕт никакого пропущенного сказуемого, тогда *И* соединяет однородные подлежащие, перед ним запятая не нужна. Мне больше нравится первый вариант, а Вам?

Comment: Мне тоже. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Да, это сложноподчиненное предложение. Кроме того, Вы пропустили запятую перед "если".

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем нужна запятая перед "если"